# GO (Golang) vendor experiment failing on mac osx

Tags: go, osx-yosemite, vendor

Having some trouble getting the go vendor experiment working with go 1.6.2 on osx.

Heres my directory structure:

```
/project
    /application
        main.go
        other.go
        /vendor
            /github.com
                /vendor_name
                    /package_name
```

I have my GOPATH set to `/Users/me/project/application`
However when I try to run any of the go tools (e.g build) it seems to be looking in `application/src` rather than `application/vendor`, getting lots of this:

```
main.go:15:2: cannot find package "github.com/facebookgo/grace/gracehttp" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec/src/github.com/facebookgo/grace/gracehttp (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/me/project/application/src/github.com/facebookgo/grace/gracehttp (from $GOPATH)
```

As you can see for go env output vendor experiment is on by default as it should be it just doesnt seem to work:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/me/project/application"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Now, the source of the funkiness may be a hangover from previous go installations. I had installed various versions of go over time, some through gvm (go version manager) and some through homebrew. So I have uninstalled gvm and the versions of go it had installed, also unstalled go with homebrew and reinstalled just 1.6.2 using homebrew.

go version output:

```
go version go1.6.2 darwin/amd64
```

which go:

```
/usr/local/bin/go
```

Any ideas what may have gone wrong here, or am I perhaps just misunderstanding how vendoring should work?

P.S. Please elt me know if you need more info, happy to provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems to be looking in application/src

Yes, go is looking in `$GOPATH/src`, both for your sources *and* for `vendor` sources folders.

Everything should be in `$GOPATH/src`

The **[vendor folder](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories)** is meant to be  importable only by code in the directory tree rooted at the parent of "`vendor`".
But it is part of your sources, and as such, should be under `$GOPATH/src`.

Comment: Thanks, i got this working. I had looked at a number of examples which seemed to suggest you could drop the /src folder. It clicked with your answer that you can drop src from within the vendor directory but the vendor directory has to be underneath /src. I really hate the way vendoring works in golang, this is a minor improvement. My new setup is to make home/me/projects my gopath, have a src folder under that and then under that I keep all my projects with their own vendor folders with individual dependencies. This seems to work.