# Golang vendor not detecting

Tags: go, build, compilation, vendor

I git cloned this specific repo https://github.com/evnix/boltdbweb into my environment in $GOPATH/src/somesetofpaths

I also ran go get on the dependencies, but with this specific dependency

go get github.com/boltdb/bolt/...

I want it in vendor rather than src/github.com/...

But when I run go build, I'm getting 
../../../github.com/evnix/boltdbweb/web/index.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/boltdb/bolt" in any of:
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec/src/github.com/boltdb/bolt (from $GOROOT)
    $GOPATH/src/github.com/boltdb/bolt (from $GOPATH)

meaning it's not looking in the vendor directory.

The thing is... it's only this package that's not looking in vendor. I have other projects in $GOPATH/src/someproject1/ , $GOPATH/src/someproject2/ that are building properly using code in $GOPATH/src/vendor. What am I missing?

This is my go env

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH=(omitted)
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: No it does. See https://engineeredweb.com/blog/2015/go-1.5-vendor-handling/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253780/go-golang-vendor-experiment-failing-on-mac-osx?rq=1 . It works with my other apps but not this one i just imported

Comment: You're right, it will walk up there (though I still wouldn't recommend it). Do you have any symlinks in your `GOPATH` or `vendor` dir? Are you trying to use any relative import paths?

Comment: Nope no symlinks. As for relative import paths, I don't think so. All importing is done through the 3rd party package https://github.com/evnix/boltdbweb and its dependencies

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is if the `github.com/boltdb/bolt` dependency is completely missing. If you vendor'ed that manually, are you sure there are no typos in the path? Are you using a vendor'ing tool to manage the dependencies?

Comment: There are no typos. If there was a typo, I think it should show cannot find package "typo" in any of: $GOPATH/..., $GOROOT/..., $GOPATH/src/vendor . No vendoring tools used either